# Access a specific line from a file, according to content

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am developing a windows store app - a media player.

I store my playlist in a file for access after the app closes. What I want to do is search for the name of the song, in the file, that is the same as the name in the listbox. Ones found I want to read the path of the song (also stored in the file) and set the source of the mediaElement accordingly.

For instance:

The user chose song "X" in the listbox then search for the line in the file where song "X" is and copy that line from the file, so that I can extract the path from it.

I am quite new to this, is this a good method? How will I do it?

Answer (score 0):

using FileStream is not good idea for read/write in most cases 
try to use some SQL it will do fantastic job for this propose .

SQLlite is small easy to use 
take a look at [this](http://www.sqllite.com/).
or SQLCampact

Answer (score 0):

How about defining a class that would store song information such as Name, Artist, Album, File Path etc. ?

Then serialize it to a XML file.

I'd rather suggest creating multiple classes. One for artist, one for album, one for track... This would allow you to add extra features to your player in the future.

Also, there might be libraries for this specific task already (WinRT API). Try researching the topic.